Erro de falta de argumentos no UserPolicy - PHP - Laravel
Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao rodar no meu servidor local.
Acontece logo apos o login.
Realizei o login algumas vezes, e apos implementar outros usuarios com acessos diferente, não abre mais o painel adm.
TypeError
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.17
10.48.11
App\Policies\UserPolicy::update(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type App\Models\User, App\Models\Usuarios given, called in /home/requisitos/compartilhada/Acacia/estudos/TCC UFPR - 2024/projeto_agendamento_acacia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 811
Minha UserPolice

O Laravel espera que o parâmetro seja do tipo App\Models\User, mas você está usando App\Models\Usuarios. Como criou essa classe? Como configurou para o Laravel usá-la como usuário?

Ola!
Foi criado a UserPolicy e criei tb a UsuarioPolicy
Assim esta minha update nas duas
* Determine whether the user can update the model.
*/
public function update(User $user, Usuarios $model): bool
{
return $user->id === $model->user_id || $user->isAdmin();
return true;
}

O erro que você está recebendo indica que há um problema com o tipo de argumento passado para o método update em sua política de usuário (UserPolicy). O método espera um objeto do tipo App\Models\User, mas está recebendo um objeto do tipo App\Models\Usuarios.
Para corrigir isso, você precisa garantir que está passando o tipo correto de usuário para o método update em sua política de usuário. Verifique onde você está chamando o método update e certifique-se de que está passando um objeto User válido.
Se você estiver usando uma instância diferente de usuário (Usuarios), pode ser necessário ajustar sua política de usuário para lidar com esse tipo de objeto. Certifique-se de que sua política está configurada para aceitar o tipo correto de usuário em todos os lugares onde é utilizada.

Ola!
Foi criado a UserPolicy e criei tb a UsuarioPolicy
Assim esta minha update nas duas
* Determine whether the user can update the model.
*/
public function update(User $user, Usuarios $model): bool
{
return $user->id === $model->user_id || $user->isAdmin();
return true;
}
